# How do I create an exception for my htaccess setting that enables friendly URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a LAMP server, but I do more website coding and design than Apache configuration. I hope my question will be clear because I don't understand the syntax of `.htaccess` files very well, and the code I have is mostly derived from tutorials on the web.

My website uses "friendly URLs", and to enable that function, I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

However, I've created a subdirectory with a whole different set of HTML under a subdirectory that I want to be able to access by going to a URL like this: `http://www.example.com/subdirectory`.

What is happening is that even if I go directly to `http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.html`, Apache still redirects to `index.php` in the root.

Is there a way I can modify my `.htaccess` file so that my `subdirectory` will be exempted from the redirection?

---

***UPDATE:***
After some experimenting, I've determined that it is exactly this line that is causing the problem (which may be obvious to people more skilled than I am with .htaccess files):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

If I comment that line out, everything *in the subdirectory* works fine (the rest of the site, of course, breaks). If I leave it in, I get the problem described above.

As suggested in an answer below, I tried changing the line to:

```
RewriteRule !^subdirectory index.php
```

But that didn't fix the problem. I also tried making a .htaccess file in the subdirectory with these contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Unfortunately, that did nothing.

My limited understanding of .htaccess syntax says that the line I already have should leave the contents of my subdirectory alone, but it is acting far more aggressively than intended.

Is there a way I can diagnose and fix this line so that it does not act upon the contents of my subdirectory?

---

***UPDATE 2:***

After some experimentation, I found that the .htaccess file in the subdirectory is not being read. If I put gibberish text in it, I don't get any errors, which seems to indicate it's not even being accessed.

I looked for reasons why my .htaccess file might not be being read, and I found that in my .conf file for the site, I need to have this code:

```
AllowOverride All
```

I have that directive in there, but the .htaccess in the subdirectory is still not being read.

What to I do to ensure the .htaccess file in the subdirectory is being read?

---

Contents of my root .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN Compress text files
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Compress text files
# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off
# BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
# END Remove Last-Modified Header

# Make all requests pass through index.php to enable "friendly URLs"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

# Turn off 'magic quotes'
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off

# Do not allow Perl script hackers, as they are probably just feeding useless Adsense "directory" sites
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Filter for most common exploits
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tool25 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.txt [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.gif [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r57shell [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99 [OR]

# deny most common except .php
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|tpl|h|ihtml|sql|ini|conf|class|bin|spd|theme|module)$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Disable .htaccess viewing from browser
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</Files>
```

---

This code is in my `/etc/apche2/apache2.conf`:

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

... and here is the contents of the conf file specific to the site in question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.local_example.com
   ServerAlias local_example.com
   ServerAdmin serveradmin@gmail.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
   <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       # pcw AllowOverride None
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
       # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
       # Commented out for Ubuntu
       #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog /home/admin/Apache_Logs/local_example.com_error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel debug

   CustomLog /home/admin/Apache_Logs/local_example.com_access.log combined
   ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "Apache still redirects to index.php" - Just to confirm, this presumably not an _external redirect_, but an _internal rewrite_? ie. The URL in the address bar does not actually change?

Comment: If `/subdirectory/index.html` is a valid file then your rule shouldn't execute due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which is skipping all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/subdirectory` is a physical directory on the filesystem and `/subdirectory/index.html` is an actual file then your current directives already include the necessary exception... the URL should not be rewritten if the requested URL maps to a physical directory or file.

However, to explicitly include an exception for the `/subdirectory` then you could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^subdirectory index.php
```

Only URLs that do not start `/subdirectory` will be processed. (Not that the directory-prefix is removed when matching the URL-path with the `RewriteRule` pattern, so it should be `subdirectory` here, not `/subdirectory`.)

Alternatively, you can create an additional `.htaccess` at `/subdirectory/.htaccess` and simply enable the rewrite engine:

```
# /subdirectory/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
```

mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so this should completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. (Note that other directives from different modules might still be processed.)

---

**UPDATE:** I cannot see anything in your `.htaccess` file that would directly cause these symptoms, however, the following does need fixing/tidying...

```
# Do not allow Perl script hackers, as they are probably just feeding useless Adsense "directory" sites
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Filter for most common exploits
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tool25 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.txt [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.gif [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r57shell [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99 [OR]
```

The 2nd code block above ("Filter for most common exploits") is incomplete and should not have a trailing `OR` flag (that would potentially block *everyone*!). These two code blocks also repeat the same code and should be combined. The `RewriteBase` directive is also redundant and can be removed. The above should be rewritten as:

```
# Do not allow Perl script hackers, as they are probably just feeding useless Adsense "directory" sites
# and Filter for most common exploits
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tool25 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.txt [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cmd.gif [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} r57shell [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c99
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The `F` flag implies `L`, so the `L` flag is not required here.

---

**UPDATE#2:** Again, I cannot see anything in your `VirtualHost` container that would cause these problems (although, to be honest, I'm struggling to even imagine what could be causing this behaviour).

However, the following line is suspicious:

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

Why do you need `MultiViews`? Also, do you need `Indexes`? Most sites will disable these options as they can expose your file structure and result in unexpected behaviour (unless that behaviour is intentional of course). However, `FollowSymLinks` is required for mod_rewrite.

If these options are not required then try removing them:

Options FollowSymLinks

Incidentally, these options can also be disabled in .htaccess with the following directive (note that here the options are preceded with `-`):

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I tried your suggestions, but unfortunately they did not work. I updated my question to reflect what I learned in the process of trying to apply your fixes, so hopefully that will narrow the scope of the problem to something more solvable.

Comment: Do you have any other (mod_rewrite) directives in the .htaccess file(s) or server config? Do you have any `<Directory>` sections in the server config that could include possibly include this subdirectory (perhaps via a regex)? Any other `AllowOverride` directives - anywhere? Just to confirm... the .htaccess file is in the document root and the subdirectory is a physical subdirectory off the document root?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I added the contents of my root .htaccess file to my question. I don't have anything in any configuration file that would specifically reference this one subdirectory I'm trying to work with. I don't know where to check for AllowOverride directives other than what I've mentioned. The only two .htaccess files are the one in the document root, and one in the subdirectory, and the subdirectory is physically in the document root as well, it's not a symlink or anything like that.

Comment: I can't see anything in your `.htaccess` file that would cause this "problem", however, there is a code block that does need fixing - I've updated my answer.

Comment: The `AllowOverride` directive could appear anywhere in the server config, VirtualHost containers, etc. Do you have just a single conf file, or do you include multiple conf (VirtualHosts) files into the main conf file? Any `Alias` directives? `RewriteOptions` directives? I think you'll need to post your server config as there would seem to be _something_ fundamental at the server level that is blocking this? However, the fact that your initial ruleset did not work is a mystery... that suggests your server does not see `/subdirectory/index.html` as a physical file on the filesystem?!

Comment: Thank you for the code fix. For locating the AllowOverride directive... this is getting beyond my abilities, which were not much to start with. I'm not sure how to to describe my configuration, but I'll try. Each virtual host on my server has it's own conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. There are about 12 sites in total, plus a `default` conf file. Might you be able to recommend a specific place to look?

Comment: Presumably each site/VirtualHost is entirely separate - no overlap in the directory structure? In which case, only the main conf file and the VirtualHost conf file for this site will be relevant. Note also that .htaccess anywhere on the filesystem directory path will also apply.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help. What do you mean by "overlap" in the directory structure? Also, what is the difference between the "main conf file" and the "VirtualHost conf file"? I thought those were the same thing? Sorry if my questions are very basic - like I said, I'm a web designer, this virtual host stuff is outside of my expertise.

Comment: "overlap" - You could have two or more entirely separate websites (ie. `VirtualHosts` / different domains) that share the same space on the filesystem - actually, that won't matter anyway, since only 1 VirtualHost will apply. "Each virtual host on my server has it's own conf file" - Each VirtualHost conf file will be _included_ (at runtime) into the main conf file. All settings specific to this website will be stored in the separate VirtualHost (conf file), not the main conf file (which simply stores all the general settings for all the websites on the server).

Comment: You'll need to check the main conf file and the conf file that relates to this VirtualHost.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. The only thing I'm still fuzzy on is what you mean by the "main" conf file. Is that the "default" in `sites-availabe`, or another file located elsewhere? Or is it the `apache2.conf` file? I've updated my question with contents from `apache2.conf`.

Comment: There is 1 conf file that contains all the (default) server settings (into which other files can be included) - this is the conf file that is processed when the server starts - that is the main/default conf, it could have different names. The VirtualHost conf file will override anything in the main/default conf file.

Comment: Find the conf file that relates to this website and add the contents to your question. It should contain a `<VirtualHost> ... </VirtualHost>` container. Inside that VirtualHost container there should be a `ServerName` directive that relates to the hostname of your website.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I've added the contents of the conf file for the site that is having the problem. Not that I really know what I'm talking about, but from the little I've learned about `.htaccess` files recently, it seems to have the right `AllowOverride All` statements.

Comment: I can't really see anything in your VirtualHost that would cause this behaviour. However, the use of `MultiViews` is a bit "suspicious". I've updated my answer with some more comments on this.

Comment: Success! Putting `Options FollowSymLinks` (taking out `Indexes` and `MultiViews`) in the virtual hosts file didn't seem to change anything, but, when I put `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` into the `.htaccess` files in the root directory, then it seemed the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory was being read. However, putting `RewriteEngine Off` in the `.htaccess` file in the subdir didn't change anything, so I went with your earlier solution of using `RewriteRule !^subdirectory index.php` in the root `.htacess` file, and then I started to see the HTML files in my subdir behave as expected!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but, to summarize the above, it seems that what ultimately worked was putting `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` and `RewriteRule !^subdirectory index.php` (two separate lines) in the root `.htaccess file`. However, for anyone who might come across this later, other tweaks mentioned above may have had a contributing effect.

Comment: Glad you got it working! `MultiViews` is the likely culprit in that case. Just to clarify, it should be `RewriteEngine On` (rather than `Off`) in the `.htaccess` file in the subdir, that way it _overrides_ the mod_rewrite directives in the parent .htaccess file. If `Options FollowSymLinks` alone in the VirtualHosts file did not work then it suggests that `MultiViews` is probably being enabled somewhere else as well (quite possible). `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` in .htaccess specifically disables those options later.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up! I changed the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file to `RewriteEngine On`, and then I was able to switch my root `.htaccess` back to it's original `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php`, which simplifies things a lot. Everything is working a lot more intuitively now that `Options -Indexes -MultiViews` is in the root `htacces` file. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: In theory, you should now be able go back to your original .htaccess file (with the addition of the changed `Options` directive), providing all the files that are being served from the subdirectory are static files on the filesystem (the specific exception for the subdirectory should not be necessary).